# Binding to form submit-event when form is dynamically added/copied

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, form-submit

I'm not sure how to bind the `submit`-event of a form that is copied into a (bootstrap) popover.

The form itself looks like this (simplified)

```
<div style="display: none;" id="theFormContainer">
    <form action="" data-myformattribute="true" >
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Prop1)
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Prop2)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Prop2, MyElements)
        <input type="submit" value="Add" />
    </form>
</div>
```

On the page there are several (search-result based) buttons which will trigger the popover to show.

In my `javascript/jQuery` (concrete it's `TypeScript`) I have the following code in the buttons click-event handler

```
var $theButton = $(evt.currentTarget);
var $theContent = $("#theFormContainer");

var $addForm = $theContent.find("form[data-myformattribute='true']");
$addForm.submit(function(){alert("form submitted")});

$theButton.popover({
    html: true,
    placement: "bottom",
    content: $theContent.html(),
    title: "some awesome title"
}).popover("show");
```

`$addForm.length` is `1`. So I guess the form inside the content has been found, no?
However, the submit trigger is never fired/hit.

How can I bind the `submit`-event of a form that is dynamically added/copied into the popover?

I already tried cloning the content with `$theContent.clone()` before the `find` call but same here.

**Edit #1**

I've also tried changing the submit-button to `<input type="submit" value="Add" id="AC08ACAB4BCD" />`

In my `javascript/jQuery` I bind the click-event this way

```
$("#AC08ACAB4BCD").on("click", function(){alert("button clicked");});
```

And even the button-click callback is never hit.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

As it's not a DOM element on page load, you can make it live:

```
var $theButton = $(evt.currentTarget);
var $theContent = $("#theFormContainer");

$theContent.delegate("form[data-myformattribute='true']","submit",function(){
  alert("form submitted")
});

$theButton.popover({
    html: true,
    placement: "bottom",
    content: $theContent.html(),
    title: "some awesome title"
}).popover("show");
```

Comment: 'not a DOM element on page load'? This I don't get as it is part of the page when loaded. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @KingKerosin, I mean it would be added to the page after loading the entire page. Of course, it's a DOM element. But not on page load. So, you can use delegate to access them at any time

Comment: Unfortunately this still is not working for me as there is still no alert showing up

Comment: @KingKerosin, you have put a part of your codes. About the submitting the form, my solution works. Look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/atuywsyh/

Comment: My code looks pretty the same as in your example. So maybe when the `popover` is initialized, the binding again goes lost?

Comment: I currently tried binding to all forms submit-events like `$("form").on("submit", ...)`. Still the callback is never hit. Any ideas?

Comment: Seems like using `$(document).on("submit", "form[data-myformattribute='true']", function(){...})` is doing the job. Could you give me any clarification on this?